# Model overwrites data in input fields when polling or pushing data from API

Tags: angularjs, rest, xsockets.net

When polling a model (object) or pushing a model from a RESTful API to AngularJS via xSockets the data in input-fields is overwritten.

Let's say I edit the first name of a user and while I edit the user xSockets or the timed polling using the $interval to refresh the model, is writing over the changes I have made to the first name before I had a chance to save.

How can I push or poll a model into the view without overwriting the input-field as I am editing?

Comment: depends how you are doing the array updates in your polling. If you break references to existing array objects is problematic. Need more understanding of your update processing. Please provide code

Comment: Hi, curious about the details here. The idea with xsockets is to avoid polling via REST and use full-duplex communication instead. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your information is a bit limited, but assuming that I understand the question correctly, you have two options.

1. You can disable realtime data refreshing on the edit page (I wouldn't let my app continuously refresh data where I am supposed to be providing input anyway).
2. You could add a change listener on your inputs that tells xSockets to not refresh the data on that field again until you have submitted the form.

Again, I'm not entirely sure what your situation is without seeing any code, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: excellent point on #1 - even using `copy` and `extend` things can still get out of synch